# How to store a method call for an object that hasn't been made yet?

Tags: python, class, object, methods, functools

I'm aware the `functools` package allows you to store functions calls to be executed later, but is there any way, using a native or 3rd-party library, to store method calls for an object that you haven't yet made, i.e. something like `functools.partial(obj.method, *args, **kwargs)` where `obj` doesn't exist yet? The idea is to make the object further along in your code and then execute the method for that object with its previously specified arguments etc. Assume the object is an instance of a class from a 3rd-party library, not a class you've made yourself, so the soluton preferably wouldn't involve modifying the code of the class.

Comment: This smells suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Can you provide more context about what you're trying to accomplish? From what you've described, I'd say the definition of the function in the class is already what you want. Given a method `my_method(self, arg1, arg2)` of class `MyClass`, you could fix some arguments to `MyClass.my_method` using `functools.partial`, and then supply the `self` argument once you have created the object.

Comment: "can my code predict the future?" no. This sounds like an XY problem. If you zoom out a little, and ask "what am I trying to accomplish", there is probably a more battle-tested way of getting that result.

Comment: It sound to me like you might want a factory closure. Do you want to see an example of how that might work? Alternatively, are you hoping to pass `obj.method` perhaps as `"obj.method"` for future evaluation?

Answer (score 2):

Use `operator.methodcaller`

```
from operator import methodcaller


f = methodcaller('method', 1, 2, 3, d=4)
f(obj)
```

has the same semantics as

```
obj.method(1, 2, 3, d=4)
```